# Deep Neural Network Not Learning Anything

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am training a simple Neural network with some Dense and Dropout Layers. But on running the fit function, there is no training taking place.
My Model is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

Model = Sequential()

Model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=12, activation='relu'))

for i in range(4):
    Model.add(Dense(2**(5+i), activation='relu'))
    Model.add(Dropout(0.5))

Model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

Model.summary()
```

```
Model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()]
)
```

```
my_callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2),
]
Model.fit(x=X, y=Y, batch_size=32, epochs=20, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=my_callbacks)
```

Result of Training are:

```
Epoch 1/20
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 9.3856 - accuracy: 0.3845 - val_loss: 9.4884 - val_accuracy: 0.3778
Epoch 2/20
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 9.3856 - accuracy: 0.3845 - val_loss: 9.4884 - val_accuracy: 0.3778
Epoch 3/20
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 9.3856 - accuracy: 0.3845 - val_loss: 9.4884 - val_accuracy: 0.3778
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f94a623ffd0>
```

I tried to see what the Model is predicting:

```
Model.predict(X)[:10]
```

Results:

```
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)
```

and so on (all predictions are 1.0).

My input dataframes are:

```
X.head(5)
```

```
    0            1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9           10          11
0   -0.572351   -0.518084   0.919925    -0.743497   0.743497    -0.50977    -0.32204    0.655011    -0.611972   0.481288    -0.445  -0.503402
1   1.747178    -0.518084   -1.087045   1.344995    -1.344995   1.96167     -0.32204    -1.526692   0.630431    0.481288    -0.445  0.734222
2   -0.572351   -0.518084   0.919925    1.344995    -1.344995   -0.50977    -0.32204    0.655011    -0.301371   -0.479087   -0.445  -0.490356
3   1.747178    -0.518084   -1.087045   1.344995    -1.344995   -0.50977    -0.32204    0.655011    0.397481    0.481288    -0.445  0.382778
4   -0.572351   -0.518084   0.919925    -0.743497   0.743497    -0.50977    -0.32204    0.655011    0.397481    -0.479087   -0.445  -0.487940
```

Y.head(10):

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    1
9    1
Name: Survived, dtype: int64
```

I am not getting what is the mistake I am doing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is more for questions about programming _per se_; you might have better luck on one of the sites devoted to stats/machine learning such as Cross Validated.

Comment: Try using sigmoid instead of softmax

Comment: in some cases when you use callback methods, the accuracy get stuck. try fitting your model without any callbacks

Comment: Tried that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sigmoid activation function if you only have 1 output neuron with 2 posibilities.
If you want to use softmax, use 2 output neurons and one hot encode your answers like: [0,1] or [1,0]

This issue is explained here: https://mc.ai/softmax-output-neurons-number-for-binary-classification/

Comment: So it means that softmax gives the argmax of all inputs. Hence my model was always predicting 1. Thanks.